# Why can't I display the result of this mysql query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT sum(rating) FROM stars WHERE post_id = 20");
echo $query;
```

It outputs:

```
Resource id #3
```

instead of 8, which is what the actual sum is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query`, after executing the query doesn't have just a number. It'll have a [Resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) just like any other query you would execute.

In order to actually get the result, treat it like you would treat any other resource:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $result[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the below.  mysql_query returns a 'resource' that represents the resultset, and to get values you need to use one of the mysql_fetch_ functions.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: Causes the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ratings.php on line 36

Comment: That's more pythonish than phpish.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, this is because the variable is a resource. Visit this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php) to learn more about PHP variable types.

It is only possible to echo strings or types that can be cast to strings. Such as int, float and objects implementing the __toString magic function.